# How do I counter double-terran in 2v2 with zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2

The question is in the title. I play as zerg most of the time and I have almost no idea what to do against the terran marine-marauder-medic combo in 2v2. The normal 1v1 strategy (banelings, basically) doesn't seem to work against these masses.

Comment: What race is your teammate?

Comment: Go for the cheese! Send in early Zerglings or you can do Ultralisks or mutalisk harrass. Keep them confined and expand :)

Comment: if they have twice the number of marines, you will have twice the number of banelings!  so it should all work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is get Infestors.  Several of them would be ideal.  When the MMM mass bunch up, drop  fungal growth on them.  Then burrow your infestors so they don't take damage and spam infested marines as quickly as possible (they're cheap energy so several infestors can create a mass of them quickly).  Also, burrowed infestors can still spawn Infested Terrans.  This is also assuming you have other units with your infestors. Roaches get kited pretty easily with Mauraders but if you use fungal growth that won't happen.

If they're a heavier Maruader build with few marines then Mutalisks will be the best counter.  But don't relay heavily on them after you take out the first wave of Marauders because a smart opponent will switch to heavy marines and vikings if he sees you've gone mutas.

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could Spawn infested marines while burrowed.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Marines in SC2 seem to be almost impossible to beat when there are enough of them, especially with marauder support, so your best chance is to destroy his supply and his reinforcements with drops, mutalisks or nydus worms while slowly killing his troops with suprise banelings (don't forget they can burrow, quite deadly if they jump out in the middle of a ball of marines) and hit-and-run tactics. Infestors work quite well, too, but if he has enough medics it will just slow him.

An MMM Ball moves relatively slowly so harassing his workers with some mutas and killing the marines that move from his base to his main unit ball should work quite well to prevent him to get enough reinforcements to fill his losses. In the worst case he has to keep half his army in his base to prevent your harass, which gives you an significant advantage at the front.

I do not recommend a frontal assault, even if you have a big ball of units yourself. It will cost a lot and then all of you just have to fill your losses and repeat from step 1. It's cheaper to hit-and-run, even if you have to sacrifice an expansion, just make sure you always have more expansions than your enemy.

Comment: The problem with this is that even if you harass the Terrans, they will just go for your base. And you're not going to win against Terran in a base-killing race, especially since Zerg tend to have fewer buildings to kill.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this depends on what your team mate is doing, you guys should be working together with scouting and communicating what the enemy is sending at you. If it's marine/marauder banelings and speedlings should definitely work if executed properly. Also infestors can turn the tide of a battle quickly. Beyond that, try to directly target the medivacs with some anti-air so that the healing support can be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the scouting in 2s is so bad you can get away with a baneling bust. If they have a solid wall (no reactors, techlabs or supply depots as vital parts of the wall) you will have to resort to hydras. The MMM ball is a whole lot more effective than your hydras but you have the macro advantage. Make sure you have one more exp than the terrans and that you spread creep everywhere. You will need that creep as the terran ball will move faster than your hydras off creep. If your macro is any good you should have a higher food count than the terran. Also mix in some infestors and fungal growth as many marines as possible.

You can't assault a tank position with hydras though. So if there are tanks you will have to resort to doom dropping to destroy their production.

It's not going to be easy, and it will feel like the terran army is a lot better. Just remember that you will have better production and more expansions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if the Terran makes a solid wall with no supply depots, how is he getting his units in and out of his base? Constantly lifting the barracks up and down, or sitting and waiting until Medivacs? Either way, if they've trapped themselves in their base you might as well take advantage of your map control and win the game.

Comment: In the higher levels, this is common. They build a solid wall with 2 raxes or a rax and a factory. When they the game is beyond the wall-busting stage, they can lift one and open it up.

Answer (score 0):

If the other team is coordinating their bioballs, then you will need to coordinate your baneling/speedling attack.  if you mass up a bunch of blings then attack by yourself, while your buddy does the same thing a minutel later, you'll be in trouble.  if you hit at the same time, the m + m will have less chance to kill all the blings before the detonate.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what race your teammate plays, but my Zerg friend likes to build Infestors to prevent the endless Terran kiting. If I manage to build fast enough, I'll have psionic storm by the enemy's mid-game push which absolutely rips apart MMM since Fungal Growth prevents them from moving. It also makes it much easier to ambush them with banelings.

Answer (score 0):

I play Terran at Diamond level 2v2 and I would suggest you scout properly. This way you can prevent them from getting very fast expansions. If you see them expand very fast just rush with Zerglings or/and Roaches.

If the Terran takes a fast expand, just expand more (3rd base). The key is to just "defend" until your macro kicks in. Then attack at different locations. As MMM is very slow you can usually pull back before the main force arrives.

This way Terran have to find the right timing. But if your scouting is good enough you will be more than prepared when they move out.

Also burrow 1-2 Banelings at good positions. They are forced to scan this way.

Comment: MMM is very slow?! Define slow.

Comment: Zerg units are generally faster than Terran units. Especially Speedlings and Mutas, even Roaches with speed upgrade are a faster than MMM without Stim. I suggest you make about 10-16 Speedlings if Terran expands too fast, otherwise go with 8-10 Mutas. A good tactic is to harass the main with Mutas and when he pulls his MMM ball back just attack the natural with Speedlings. As soon as you see his MMM pull back. This works agains most Terran up to Diamond, as many do not know how to split their army properly.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest is Broodlords if you can get them.

Comment: usually bioballs can push before broodlords are really an option.